# Turning lights on and off

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a program where when you click on a light the lightbulb will turn on, and then if you click on it again it will turn off. I have onClick but no matter which one I clikc the first one always turns on. Can somebody help so that the clicked on light will turn on?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <img id="light1" onclick="changeImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

        <img id="light2" onclick="changeImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

        <img id="light3" onclick="changeImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

        <img id="light4" onclick="changeImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">


    <script>
        function changeImage() {
            var image1 = document.getElementById('light1');
            if (image1.src.match("bulbon")) {
                image1.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
            } else {
            image1.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
            }
        }
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is because of this var image1 = document.getElementById('light1');, you are selecting only that 1 light

Comment: hint: `var image1 = document.getElementById('light1');`

Comment: protip: Learn to attach event handlers instead of using inline `onclick=something()`

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, event handlers get a special variable called `this`, which refers to the element from which the event was *fired* (in this case the light bulb that was clicked), you can use it like this:

```
function changeImage() {
    if (this.src.match("bulbon")) {
        this.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
    } else {
        this.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
    }
}
```

Notice the difference from your code. You were always making changes to the *first* lightbulb, accessed by id using the API `document.getElementById('light1')`.

Comment: I was about to post this too but you beat me to it VOTE UP :).. this should work I believe !

Answer (score 0):

You're pointing at the same DOM node in your function despite registering an event handler on multiple nodes.

You should use the `this` keyword to use currently clicked node as the context during the function's execution.